# Cause of getting:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: windows, scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm a student,this is my first time to learn spark.when I configure the environment on intellj and run spark,there have some error,I don't know how to solve it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray overrides final method toBuffer.()Lscala/collection/mutable/Buffer;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:53)
    at com.txf.LoadLibSVMFile$.delayedEndpoint$com$txf$LoadLibSVMFile$1(txf.scala:21)
    at com.txf.LoadLibSVMFile$delayedInit$body.apply(txf.scala:16)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
```

It is compiled with jdk-1.8.0 and scala-2.10.7 on intellj.
The following code is my test code.

```
package com.txf
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object LoadLibSVMFile extends App{
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LogisticRegressionMail").setMaster("local")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val examples: RDD[LabeledPoint] = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "hello.txt")

  println(examples.first)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you are using a very old version of **Spark** I would suspect the error is using **Scala** `2.10.7` _(That is like 4 years old!)_ Most versions of **Spark** are meant to be used with **Scala** `2.11.x` _(usually the `x` is an `8`)_. And the most recent ones _(**Spark** `2.4.x` upwards)_ support **Scala** `2.12.x`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try to change the version of scala

Comment: @TXF Have you resolved this ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue..
Spark Version installed in Windows: spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7....
Scala plugin installed in intellij: 2.13.2
Java installed in windows: 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Got the fix for this issue


Mismatch in Spark and Scala supportive version pops out these issue(s). Scala compile version might be higher than the run-time version.

With Spark, that means that the Spark version used to compile is different from the one deployed (on the machine or cluster). Aligning the versions between development and runtime should solve this issue.


Do check the version compatibility in the Spark docs

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/